# Cannot insert data into Oracle DB with SYSDATE sql query

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, liquibase

I have my liquibase changeset as shown below

```
    <changeSet id="1739718925270-1" author="abc">
        <insert tableName="users">
            <column name="user_id" value="abc@gmail.com"/>
            <column name="created_at" valueComputed="((SYSDATE - date '1970-01-01')*24*60*60*1000)"/>
            <column name="modified_at" valueComputed="((SYSDATE - date '1970-01-01')*24*60*60*1000)"/>
        </insert>
    </changeSet>
```

I have to insert the data with the help of sql query **only** in the oracle database so I tried below sql query but its syntax is wrong so it gives the below error

query:

```
INSERT INTO users 
(user_id, created_at, modified_at)
VALUES
('abc@gmail.com', SYSDATE - TO_DATE('1970-01-01')*24*60*60*1000, SYSDATE - TO_DATE('1970-01-01')*24*60*60*1000);
```

Error:

```
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected NUMBER got DATE
00932. 00000 -  "inconsistent datatypes: expected %s got %s"
```

What is the correct syntax since I feel my syntax is wrong, my column is of epoch time value but I am not sure how can I insert?

please help

my existing table:

[existing table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6volI.png)

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
TO_DATE('1970-01-01')*24*60*60*1000
```

is wrong; you can't multiply date with a number. What is e.g. 3rd of March 2023 * 24?

Perhaps you meant

```
(SYSDATE - TO_DATE('1970-01-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd')) * (24*60*60*1000)
```

so you'd get difference of two date values (which is number of days between) and then multiply it by *something* (a number), so - result is then `NUMBER` datatype.

---

Also, with `to_date`, **always** specify format model.